# Qt Saving JSON and PDF file to Path

Tags: json, qt, file, save

I have two file for application. One's is data file saving with QJSON the other one is pdf which is include app's info.

I want to save this two file into path (selecting by users). How can I get user's selection file path? Fallowing code block has my pdf saving method and QJSON method.
-Saving PDF;

```
void MainWindow::saveAsPdf(){

   QString html=
           "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><b>Sample : </b><a>"+ui->sampleText->text()+"</a><br><b>Operator : </b> <a>"+ui->operatorText->text()+"</a><br><b>Method : </b> <a>"+ui->evalText->text()+" </a><br>"+
           "<b>Date : </b> <a>"+ui->date->text()+"</a><br><br>"+
           "<b>Mixer : </b> <a>300 </a>"+
           "<b>Moisture Content : </b> <a>"+ui->moistureText->text()+"</a><br>"+
           "<a>Consistency </a><b></b><a>with waterabsorption </a><a>"+ui->absorptionText->text()+"</a><br><br>"+
           "<b>Waterabsorption (correct for 500 FU) : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>Waterabsorption (correct for 14.0 %) : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>DevelopmentTime : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>Stability : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>Degree of Softening (10 min after begin) : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>Degree of Softening (ICC/ 12 min after max) : </b><a></a><br>"+
           "<b>Farinograph quality number : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>Remarks : </b><a>"+ui->remaskText->text()+"</a><br>"+
           "</body>"+
           "</html>";

   QTextDocument parent;
   parent.setHtml(html);
   QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
   printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
   printer.setColorMode(QPrinter::Color);
   //printer.getPageMargins(*left);
   printer.setOutputFileName(ui->operatorText->text());
   QPrintDialog*dlg = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);
   dlg->setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Print Document"));

   if(dlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {

       QPainter painter(&printer);
       painter.drawPixmap(500, 5500, QPixmap(ui->qcustom->toPixmap(800,500,10.0)));
       parent.setDefaultFont(QFont("Times", 200));
       parent.drawContents(&painter);
       painter.end();

    }
   delete dlg;
```

}

-Saving JSON file in other class method, it is get only file path:

```
 formula.savejson("/home/elif/Desktop/"+ui->operatorText->text()+".txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to select a path, have a look at `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory()`